# My Visual Studio Setup does not install missing pre-requisite or tells user if the prerequisite is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I'm creating setup file with Visual Studio 2010 and giving to my users but when they install them, it gives them this error. [Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZWLO.jpg)

I know clearly that they are missing SQL Server Compact 3.5 but why it doesn't install the required pre-requisites when the application is installing or when the program runs.

Despite I have checked that if the pre-requisites are missing, it should install for them from vendor's website.[Picture Below]

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OURvD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but you've told your setup project that the prerequisites should be downloaded from the vendor's website, so is it possible that your users don't have access to that website, or possibly are being blocked due to some administrative or firewall rules?

It's probably better to select 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' which will put the items alongside your own installation files.  At least that's a simple starting point to determine whether the problem is with some lack of external connectivity.

Comment: But then will it be packaged into msi setup? Or do I have to upload pre-requisite as well?

Comment: Yes, if you say get this from my application then it will be packaged up with your bundle.